# Suppress printing of total line with ls -l

Tags: bash, ls

`ls -l` adds a total line (for total number of blocks) at the top of its output. Is there a direct way to suppress this line from the output? I know I can pipe the output into another command to delete the first line, but I am wondering if I am missing a simple option to suppress that line in the first place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you're not missing a simple option to drop the `total` line, at least not when listing the contents of a directory (including the current one, with no arguments). For example, with GNU `ls`, the `-l`, `-g`, `-n`, `-o` and `-s` options cause the `total` line [to be displayed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n2784), with no option to disable it:

```
if (format == long_format || print_block_size)
{
  const char *p;
  char buf[LONGEST_HUMAN_READABLE + 1];

  DIRED_INDENT ();
  p = _("total");
  DIRED_FPUTS (p, stdout, strlen (p));
  DIRED_PUTCHAR (' ');
  p = human_readable (total_blocks, buf, human_output_opts,
                      ST_NBLOCKSIZE, output_block_size);
  DIRED_FPUTS (p, stdout, strlen (p));
  DIRED_PUTCHAR ('\n');
}
```

This is actually [mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html).

However, if you specify the files to list, rather than a directory, `ls` won’t show the total; the `-d` option causes directories to be treated as files, producing the desired result, as mentioned by [Costas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/89144/costas):

```
ls -ld *
```

will produce the same output as

```
ls -l
```

minus the `total` line, as long as your shell doesn’t include hidden files when expanding `*` (`dotglob`) and as long as the current directory doesn’t contain so many files that the expansion of `*` exceeds the maximum command-line length.

You can specify a directory too (`ls -ld /path/to/directory/*`) but the output will list files with the given path, unlike `ls -l /path/to/directory`.